# Map not showing anything

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

Cursor c;
MyDataBase mdb;
ArrayList<String> stop;




GoogleMap gmaps;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    mdb=new MyDataBase(this);
    mdb.open();
    double[] latitude=new double[97];
    double[] longitude=new double[97];
    stop=new ArrayList<String>();
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    stop=intent.getStringArrayListExtra("stopslist");
    for(int i=0;i<stop.size();i++)
    {
    c=mdb.getStops(stop.get(i));
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        latitude[i]=c.getDouble(2);
        longitude[i]=c.getDouble(3);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),latitude[i]+"  "+longitude[i], 1).show();  

    }
    }

    SupportMapFragment map = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    gmaps=map.getMap();
    gmaps.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LatLng ll=new LatLng(latitude[0], longitude[0]);
   gmaps.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll));
   gmaps.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

   for(int i=0;i<stop.size();i++)
   { 
       ll=new LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]);
       gmaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .title(stop.get(i))
       .snippet(stop.get(i)+" "+"Metro Station")
       .position(ll));
   }

}
```

}

**Edit:**

This is the code I have written to pin markers on the Map, but when I press the button, it goes to google maps and remains blank. Can Someone tell what is the problem here.?

Comment: have you referenced google play services library project in your android project?

Comment: yes I did.. But still these issues are there..

Comment: how did you do it. and also check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2 using map api v2 right?

Answer (score 0):

just add  google play services library to your project.

go to your project -> properties -> android -> in project build target section -> check google api

Answer (score 0):

Once check this in your manifest:

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: @Raghunandan Why not?

Comment: @shylendra https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2. check this you will know yourself

Comment: @Akshat Have you added google play library to your project? and which is located at same workspace

Comment: @Akshat which api are you using api 1 is deprecated switch to api v2 and it looks like you are using api v1.

Answer (score 0):

download the corresponding **android-google-maps-api.jar** [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidgooglemapsapi11jar.htm) to avoid the errors and check the manisfest too

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why are people here trying to confuse you and to make you use an API that is deprecated for almost a year now, But the answers here are wrong.

There is no need in adding this line of code:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

as this line of code belongs to the previous `API v1`. `API v2` is configured very differently.
And actually the code the you presented is code for `API V2`, so you are on the right track.

Please check this 2 blog posts to make sure you have committed all the steps correctly:

[Google Maps API V2 key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

and:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

And if this doesn't help you, please with use your XML Manifest file.